In Powershell Script Set IP address, subnet mask, Default Gateway & Taking system into Domain both commands not working one after another
I am new in PowerShell. I created a CSV file and inside this CSV file I stored Computer Type, is this system used nor not, Ip Address, Subnet Mast DNS1, DNS2, Domain Name, username, password, time zone.
CSV File photo
Using PowerShell I import this file & stored all information of this csv file into Variables.
When I am changing the IP address of client using PowerShell & after that renaming the computer and taking into domain this both commands didn't work one after another.
if I run both commands, it will give error this is the error "Error: Computer 'zx' failed to join domain 'pritam.ugale' from its current workgroup '12' with following error message: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted."
Error msg
if I remove the changing IP address code from script and run the script then it will take system into domain without any issue. I don't understand why both commands didn't work.
Here is my Code:
# Get input from user 
$selection = Read-Host "`n`nPlease select your choice `n`n1. Cal `n2. Noncal `n3. Aria `n`nEnter Choice(Eg: Enter 1 for cal Enter 2 for non cal) "

# Checking what input user given here 
if($selection -eq 1 -or $selection -eq 2 -or $selection -eq 3  )
{
    # If user select one " 1 " means user selected Cal 
    if($selection -eq 1)
    {
        $selection1 = 'cal'         
        Write-Host "`n`nGreat!! you selected $selection1`n`n " -ForegroundColor Green 
       
        # Iterate through each row in the CSV data
        foreach ($row in $csvData)
        {
            # Check if the computername is "cal" and the used value is "no"
            if ($row.ctype -eq "cal" -and $row.used -eq "no") 
            {

                #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                # Changing IP address start here 
                try
                {                
                    # Set IP address, subnet mask, and default gateway                       
                         netsh interface ip set address name = $InterfaceAlias static $row.IP_address $Subnet_mask $DG
    
                    # Set DNS servers
                        Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias $InterfaceAlias -ServerAddresses ($PrimaryDNS, $SecondaryDNS)

                        Write-Host "1. Hmmm The IP Address ( " -NoNewline #.....................................................No 1 One
                        Write-Host $row.IP_address -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline
                        Write-Host " ) & DNS has been assign to this computer "$row.CNAME
                    
                }catch { Write-Host "Failed to set the IP setting or DNS Setting. Error: $_" -f Red }
                # Changing IP address END here 
                #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                # Taking system into domain Start here
                try
                {
                   $rowcname =  $row.CNAME
                   Add-Computer -DomainName $DOMAIN -credential $credential -NewName $rowcname -ErrorAction Stop
                   Write-Host "`n2. Computer rename & inside of this domain " -NoNewline #......................................................No 5 
                   Write-Host $DOMAIN -ForegroundColor Green
                }
                catch
                {
                    Write-Host "`nFailed to take system into domain. Error: $_"
                }                
                # Taking system into domain End here
                #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
                #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                # Collecting Serial Number here.
                try
                {                
                   $serialNumber = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber
                    $pcname = hostname
                    if($row.CNAME -eq $pcname){
                    $row.sr = $serialNumber  
                    }
                }catch { Write-Host "Failed collect the serial number: $_" -f Red }
                # Collecting Serial Number End here. 
                #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------            
                
                # Change the used value to "yes"****               
                $row.used = "yes"                
                # Break out of the loop after the first match
               break 
            } 
            
        }         
    } # user slection one finished here *
                                #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

   
       

}
else{write-host "`n$selection Mission Abort" -ForegroundColor Red}



I am trying to take input from csv file and perform this activity. 1.Checking all computer name is not more than 16 characters.
2. Checking all computer IP is CORRECT
3. (User Account Control) has been adjusted to Never Notify Mode
4. Set Time Zone
5. Disabling the Firewall
6. Set IP address, subnet mask, and default gateway
7. Taking system into domain
8. Collecting Serial Number

it is logical to assume that when changing the ip address, the connection with the domain is lost

@rinatgadeev what solution for this?
